# I am trying to create a calculated field from multiples columns by each row in Tableau

Tags: sql, oracle, tableau-api, calculated-field

I have 5 columns.

```
SAMPLE           HIGH          MEDIUM         LOW    TOTAL

A________________5______________4______________7_____16

B________________5______________4______________7_____16

C________________5______________4______________7_____16

D________________5______________4______________7_____16
```

I want to be able to calculate for each sample the percentage of  High Medium Low.

- High/ total = new value
- medium/total = new value
- low/total=new value

How do I do this in Tableau?

Answer (score 1):

You can read [here](http://onlinehelp.tableausoftware.com/v8.0/public/online/en-us/calculations_calculatedfields_ex1create.html) for more details, but the general way is to right click on the Dimensions or Measures small window and then click on Create Calculated Field.

[image]

When the windows opens, in your case, you'll want to create a new name for the 'New Value', and then for the Formula section you should put:

```
[HIGH]/[TOTAL]
```

Just make sure that these are recognized as floats or integers (and not strings). If you select the variables in the Fields section, you are more likely to get exactly what you want. Also, there is a preview on the right of the data type.

[image]

Comment: I actually found out why I was not able to get the desired results.

I Had to write it as SUM(HIGH)/SUM(TOTAL)   for it to show the correct aggregate Data calculation.

Comment: FYI, your question said you want to compute those ratios "for each sample". If so, to calculate a ratio for each individual data row, then you need a simple calculated field such as "[HIGH]/[TOTAL]". But if you want a single aggregate calculation for each group of rows (as defined by the discrete dimensions in your view), then you need to include the aggregation in the calculation, such as "SUM([HIGH])/SUM([TOTAL])". Two kinds of calculated fields for two different purposes.